# Group related product attributes

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have a products table:

```
products
-id
-name
-image
```

And a product_atts table:

```
product_attributes
-product_id (FK)
-size (1, 2)
-memebership (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 11)
-price
```

Now, when querying the `product_attributes` table and joining the `products` table, I get all of the variations:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Product 1
            [image] => Product1.png
            [size] => 1
            [membership] => 1
            [price] => 0.00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Product 1
            [image] => Product1.png
            [size] => 1
            [membership] => 2
            [price] => 0.00
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Product 1
            [image] => Product1.png
            [size] => 1
            [membership] => 3
            [price] => 0.00
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Product 1
            [image] => Product1.png
            [size] => 1
            [membership] => 4
            [price] => 0.00
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Product 1
            [image] => Product1.png
            [size] => 1
            [membership] => 6
            [price] => 0.00
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Product 1
            [image] => Product1.png
            [size] => 1
            [membership] => 11
            [price] => 0.00
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Product 1
            [image] => Product1.png
            [size] => 2
            [membership] => 1
            [price] => 0.00
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Product 1
            [image] => Product1.png
            [size] => 2
            [membership] => 2
            [price] => 0.00
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Product 1
            [image] => Product1.png
            [size] => 2
            [membership] => 3
            [price] => 0.00
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Product 1
            [image] => Product1.png
            [size] => 2
            [membership] => 4
            [price] => 0.00
        )

    [10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Product 1
            [image] => Product1.png
            [size] => 2
            [membership] => 6
            [price] => 0.00
        )

    [11] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Product 1
            [image] => Product1.png
            [size] => 2
            [membership] => 11
            [price] => 0.00
        )

)
```

Is there a way that I can get a result that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Product 1
            [image] => Product1.png
            [size] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [0] => 1,
                        [1] => 2                        
                    )
            [membership] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [0] => 1,
                        [1] => 2,
                        [2] => 3,
                        [3] => 4,
                        [4] => 6,
                        [5] => 11                       
                    )
            [price] => 0.00
        )
)
```

It makes it so much easier to then use this data in my UI, etc.

Comment: So what does your query look like?

Answer (score 0):

You might not already have realized it but using Eloquent, you already have everything this way. As soon as you create your relationships in your models, you just need a root model to reach every single one related to it.

Let's say that you have your Product model:

```
<?php

class Product extends Eloquent {

}
```

and your Products Details model:

```
<?php

class ProductDetail extends Eloquent {

}
```

So you can build a relation between them

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

    public function details()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('ProductDetail');
    }

}
```

And now if your controller pass to your UI a list of models:

```
public function index()
{
   return View::make('site.products')->with('products', Product::all());
}
```

In your UI you'll be able to:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($products as $product)
        <li>
            <p>Product: $product->name</p>
            <p>Sizes:</p>
            <ul>
                @foreach($product->details as $detail)
                    <li>
                        {{$detail->size}}
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for this... but the "details" aren't coming through at all. I've got my models names the exact same thing as you have, except I added the `protected $table = 'product_tags';` in the `ProductDetail` model.

Comment: Odd. This is exactly what I'm using here. Do a dd($product->details) and paste.laravel.com your results. Those are mines in Product: http://puu.sh/3fae8.png

Comment: Details are coming, you have a collection of ProductDetail. As an example: ["product_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["size"]=> string(1) "1" ["membership"]=> string(1) "6". What are you expecting to have?

Comment: Well, your foreach loop makes sense, but it isn't working for me ... I can't loop over the details. So I can't extract "size" or "membership" ... is there some other way that I can show you what my database looks like as well as my Models?

Comment: So, this `(@foreach($product->details as $detail))` is not working, then what do you get if you `dd($detail)` inside that loop? Does it enters the loop?

Comment: Again you have the correct data: an instance of ProductDetail, then a simple `$detail->membership` should give you `1`.

Comment: I see that the data is coming through since I made one change, but I'm apparently not looping over it correctly. I need all possible size options grouped together, and all possible membership options groups together (for a select). In the 'product_details' table, I've got a row for each variation ... so when I display all "size" options, I get repeats. What the best way to combine the same results with Eloquent?

Comment: Ah, you need that data for another select, not displaying it? That might not be the best approach then, but you can always `$memberships[] = $detail->membership;` inside that loop. So you better say in the thread what you're trying to achieve, with that next query you're about to do, because there many shortcuts in Laravel.

Comment: Is there a better way to query product details for this purpose then?

Comment: What purpose, state in your post what the purpose is, what query are you trying to build using this data you getting? Probably your next query can be done using some joins, but to get data the way you want, you have two options: using some loops to get the info or going deeper in MySQL and see if it can return array columns, I'm not sure it can and then use raw queries in laravel to get your data. Wich sounds like a lot of trouble.